# Работа с файлами

Tags: php, denwer, mysql

Привет всем. Столкнулся недавно с такой вот проблемой. Пишу сайт на php, реализовал страницу новостей, на которую добавляются изображения, текст... через редактор, используя mysql (работаю в denwer-е). Хочу сделать, чтобы можно было добавлять файл в формате doc, docx в редактор, а на странице новостей выводилась ссылка для скачивания этого файла (например, когда мы качаем музыку с сайтов, выкладывают ссылки mp3, rar, zip). При нажатии на эту ссылку выводится заголовок "Открыть", "Сохранить", "Отмена", если кто знает, как это реализовать или какую-нибудь литературу для этого, помогите плиз... Вот некий код в редакторе.

Загрузка документов

```
if(isset($_POST['savedoc'])) {
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
      // Проверяем пришел ли файл
      if( !empty( $_FILES['fdoc']['name'] ) ) {
        // Проверяем, что при загрузке не произошло ошибок
        if ( $_FILES['fdoc']['error'] == 0 ) {
          // Если файл загружен успешно, то проверяем - графический ли он
          //if( substr($_FILES['fdoc']['type'], 0, 5)=='docum' ) {
            // Читаем содержимое файла

            $docum = file_get_contents( $_FILES['fdoc']['tmp_name'] );
            // Экранируем специальные символы в содержимом файла
            $idn = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['idn'] );
            $dname = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['dname'] );
            $docum = mysql_escape_string( $docum );
            $aut = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['aut'] );
            $align = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['align'] );
            $del = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['del'] );
            // Формируем запрос на добавление файла в базу данных
            $query="INSERT INTO `docs` VALUES(NULL, '".$idn."', '".$dname."', '".$docum."', '".$aut."', '".$align."', '".$del."')";
            // После чего остается только выполнить данный запрос к базе данных
            mysql_query( $query ); 
            /* Выполняем запрос. Если произойдет ошибка - вывести ее. */
            #or die(mysql_error());
          //}
        }
      }                    
    }        
  }
```

Документы

```
 <p><form action="" method="post"  ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
 <span class="redst1">Загрузка документов:</span> 
    <input type="file" name="fdoc">
    <input name="idn" type="hidden" value="$id" />
    <input name="savedoc" type="submit" value="Загрузить" /><p>
    Название: <input name="dname" style="background:#FFFF99" type="text" size="20"  value="$dname"><p>
    Автор текста: <input name="aut" style="background:#FFFF99" type="text" size="20" class="autor" value="$aut"> 
</form><p>
```

Здесь возможны ошибки, в силу моего плохого знания php... Проблема заключается в выводе этого дела на странице новостей, там я пока ничё не делал... (

Answer (score 2):

Вы загрузили все данные из txt в бд, не было в этом необходимости. Достаточно было загрузить файл на сервер

```
move_uploaded_file($filename, "/home/localhost/www/uploads/");
```

И записать его название в базу

```
$query="INSERT INTO `docs` VALUES(NULL, '".$idn."', '".$dname."', '".$filename."', '".$aut."', '".$align."', '".$del."')";
```

Ну и вывести это дело ссылкой

```
<a href='/uploads/".$filename."'>Скачать</a>
```

Comment: ну да...просто делал по аналогии с изображениями, код не менял.Тут всё проще  оказалось)пасиб)

Comment: есть же умные люди на свете)

Answer (score 0):

Загружайте файл в директорию например `"loads/".$_POST['file']['name']`. Как это делать, тут подробно описано: [upload файлов, и все с этим связанное](http://php.su/articles/?cat=protocols&page=001).

Записывайте путь к файлу в БД. И выводите из БД вместе с новостями адрес файла для скачки.

Comment: Спасибо.Попробуем)))